# managing common libraries in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angular, frontend

I am developing an application with a few modules. Each module is individually deploy-able on the server. I am using Angular for my UI.

Because I have 4 modules, I obviously have 4 different Angular projects, setup & files.

Though there are certain differences like routing, controllers, views, the external frameworks, libraries used can be very similar and I do not want to replicate all of them.

Hence I wish to have a common project/folder/directory and use these in different modules. this way I can avoid redundancy (if it can be called that). Can someone please help me understand if my thought process is correct? If so how can I achieve this?

Comment: any reason you not using a package manager? npm or bower and then maintain a package.json for each application?

Comment: Can you point to some tutorials for a start and links. Which package manager is good?

Comment: @Jacob how will this help on sharing business logic code?

Comment: I obviously do not want to share business logic, I am not sure why you get that impression. I would not want to share business logic , but I don't want to refer angularjs n times and any framework used multiple times and have the hassle of upgrading or maintaining it multiple projects when needed.

Comment: something like this is a good start http://blog.npmjs.org/post/114584444410/using-angulars-new-improved-browserify-support

Comment: Thanks @Jacob I appreciate your quick reply and support. A naive question may be? Is NPM GRUNT/GULP in the same bucket how are they different or similar?

Comment: npm is a package manager and gulp/grunt is a build tool. execute code on server before/after deploy. which one is best is a personal preference.

Comment: @Immortal it definitely sounded to me like you have some classes or interfaces you wrote you want to share between your 4 projects. Forgive me for misunderstanding you there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a third party package manager like npm or bower. You can then add the libraries during build time with browserify or custom gulp/grunt code.

You can then  bundle all you libraries into a single file and include it in you application.